# Using log4j in eclipse RCP doesn't work

Tags: eclipse, log4j, eclipse-rcp

I want to use the log4j API in my eclipse4 RCP (Kepler).

1. Created a new Project "Plug-in from Existing JAR Archives". I added the log4j.jar with the help of the wizard.
2. In the Manifest of the new plugin under runtime I made sure that the 3 packages "com.ibm.log4j", "com.ibm.log4j.helpers" and "com.ibm.log4j.net" are exported.
3. In the plugin where I want to use the login functionallity I added the new plugin as dependency.
4. When I try to use one of the classes e. g. the Logger class the only proposal is to import java.util.logging. Which means I'm unable to access the log4j API.

I have followed this thread very closely: [How to use log4j in eclipse rcp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994883/how-to-use-log4j-in-eclipse-rcp?rq=1) I even watched the video multiple times to make sure I did nothing wrong. Still no success?

I really need some help here. I'm pretty close to just stuffing the jar file into every new plugin I add to my RCP.......

Comment: I can access the Category class which is just fine for me. No idea why the rest of the API isn't exposed.

Comment: Have you checked your newly created project MANIFEST file? What is under the "Runtime" tab? Are all the required packages exported?

Comment: Like i mentioned in step 2:  I made sure that the 3 packages "com.ibm.log4j", "com.ibm.log4j.helpers" and "com.ibm.log4j.net" are exported. This means the Runtime tab yes!

Comment: OK, but are you sure there is a Logger class in one of these packages?

Comment: Now you got a point. I have just been following some tutorials and each of them used the Logger class so I assumed it should be packaged without even looking. I may have an outdated version of the jar file... Well I'm complettly happy using the Category class. I'm now trying to figure out why I'm unable to configure the logger with a fragment plugin :(