# How to configure org.apache.log4j plugin?

Tags: java, logging, eclipse-plugin, log4j, slf4j

log4j is available both in jar form and in plugin form.

If it is used in plugin form, then how to configure it?

**UPDATE**

I want to log my application, both with `log4j` and `slf4j`.

For example, the following code in activator has no any output in debugging console:

```
    public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        super.start(context);
        plugin = this;
        log.info("Started");
    }
```

I can initialize `log` both with `slf4j`

```
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Activator.class);
```

or with `log4j`

```
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Activator.class);
```

`slf4j` later reports some warnings

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://104.fwk1075417105:13/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://104.fwk1075417105:27/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
```

`log4j` is silent. Probably it logs to different place -- hence I want to configure it.

**UPDATE 2**

I turned on `log4j.debug` and determined, that it takes `log4j.properties` from plugin `org.eclipse.xtext.logging`. This plugin is not in dependencies and can be turned off from runtime configuration.

That case `log4j` starting to swore that it has no appender for logger.

It still ignores `log4g.properties` which is inside my own plugin. So the question persists: how to configure `log4j`?

**UPDATE 3**

Once I have removed `org.eclipse.xtext.logging` and returned it back, it stops working anymore.

The following is in log:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-01-28 23:37:18.016
!MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-01-28 23:37:18.017
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.xtext.logging_1.2.15.v201309030823 [107] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.xtext.logging 2 0 2014-01-28 23:37:18.017
!MESSAGE Constraints from the fragment conflict with the host: Import-Package: org.eclipse.core.runtime; version="0.0.0"
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.xtext.logging 2 0 2014-01-28 23:37:18.017
!MESSAGE Constraints from the fragment conflict with the host: Import-Package: org.osgi.framework; version="1.5.0"
```

What does it mean?

With that `log4j` is unable to find properties file anymore.

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: Are you trying to log your application's loggable entries or those of Maven?

Comment: @Behe I want to "configure org.apache.log4j plugin". Have you read the title?

Comment: So why can't you use the jar then?

Comment: `jar` also does not work, but by slightly different reason. it also does not log, but with `log4j` explicitly saying it can't find logger. it ignores `log4j.properties` in classpath

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use log4j in eclipse rcp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994883/how-to-use-log4j-in-eclipse-rcp)