# Logger for Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to find the best (easiest) logger to make CSV file with my output, I have tried log4j but it seems only to work with JAVA application, and I need to run it as an eclipse plugin.

I have searched the internet for everything, but I always seem to end up getting loggers that only work with java. (this is a java code but needs to run as eclipse plugin)

Comment: What do you mean by 'Eclipse application'? A plug-in running as part of Eclipse? An Eclipse RCP (e3 or e4)? Eclipse plug-ins can log in the main Eclipse .log file using APIs provided by Eclipse.

Comment: Log4J can be used in Eclipse applications, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994883/how-to-use-log4j-in-an-eclipse-rcp) and also [this article](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseLogging/article.html) on Vogella

Comment: yes it eclipse plugin sorry